# How to include open source licenses (and what to include) in a Dockerized, Nginx hosted website?

Tags: licensing

We are building and hosting a website for our company that is built with HTML/CSS as usual. However, in writing those, SCSS was used, all JS files were written completely from Dart source. I wonder if we should include open source licenses for the technology that we used in a separate "Acknowledgement" page in my website.

Which technology that I should include?

- The library that I included in my Dart/SCSS project, which are also transpiled into CSS/JS?
- The licenses for the programming languages (Dart, SCSS, even Go for backend)?
- The backend technology and libraries?
- The infrastructure technology (Nginx, Nginx module, and Docker)?

Can anyone explain which that I should include and which are not and why?